# Renaming pre-existing table Field name using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, python-2.7

I am using PyQGIS with QGIS 2.84.

This is the code I have used:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

parking_layer_field_names = [str(i.name()) for i in point_layer3.pendingFields()]

layer.startEditing()
for key, field in enumerate(layer.pendingFields()):
    if str(field.name()) != parking_layer_field_names [key]:                
        layer.renameAttribute(key, 'new')
iface.vectorLayerTools().stopEditing(layer)
```

The error thrown by this code:

```
'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'renameAttribute' See log for more details
```

Comment: A field cannot be renamed, you can add a new one, calculate and remove the old field. Note your code isn't very efficient, it's calling rename (which doesn't exist) for every field that is not equal to the current key being iterated.. what is it you think that this code does?

Comment: The code checks if the field name is one of the names in the parking_layer_field_names and if its not then i am just trying to replace that name with the name in the parking_layer_field_names list on that particular index @MichaelStimson .Please correct me if i am wrong  :)

Comment: What i exactly want to do here is that i want all the selected data from a Vector layer into a new one with Full field names and respective data for each field for all the features.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking for **if key.upper() in parking_layer_field_names** where **parking_layer_field_names = [str(i.name()).upper() for i in point_layer3.pendingFields()]** to check in a case insensitive way if the key exists in parking_layer_field_names before trying to call it; pendingFields returns a list but in your loop you're treating the enumeration as a dictionary. On inspection of the API there is a renameField method which renames a field but doesn't persist it. If you want the fields to match you can add a new field of the right type and calculate the values from the old field.

Comment: But here key is an int index no not a string.

Comment: But you're making it into a string with **parking_layer_field_names = [str(i.name())...]** and then using it *like a dictionary, which it's not*. See https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a49ecbcf5b64bc69f354cb33411bb1261 pendingFields returns a list. If all you're checking is that the field.name (note no parentheses, it's a property not a method) is not in the list parking_layer_field_names use the **in** operator, a more detailed explanation at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators (example 5).

Comment: Listen @MichaelStimson I have checked the above code in QGIS 3.4 and its working as fine as anything thats the reason i have posted this question to know if something like that exists in QGIS 2.84.